# How can I determine general formula of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find general formula of the sequence $(x_n)$  defined by
$$x_1=1, \quad x_{n+1}=\dfrac{7x_n + 5}{x_n + 3}, \quad \forall n>1.$$
I tried
put $y_n = x_n + 3$, then $y_1=4$ and
$$\quad y_{n+1}=\dfrac{7(y_n-3) + 5}{y_n }=7 - \dfrac{16}{y_n}, \quad \forall n>1.$$
From here, I can't solve it. How can I determine general formula of above sequence?

With *Mathematica*, I found $x_n = \dfrac{5\cdot 4^n-8}{4^n+8}$. I want to know a method to solve problem, than have a given formula.

Comment: What makes you think that there is an explicit formula?

Comment: Also, you should have $$y_{n+1}=10-\frac{16}{y_n}$$

Comment: @Frpzzd, With Mathematica, I Found the formula is `(5 4^n - 8)/(4^n + 8)`

Comment: Oh, you should add that to the question! That is very good to now; now all that remains is to prove it by induction.

Comment: I want to find a general method, not a given formulas.

Comment: You might try assuming that the formula is in the form
$$x_n=\frac{a\cdot b^n+c}{b^n+d}$$
for similar recurrences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the function being iterated is a projective-linear function, it follows that if you let
$$ \begin{bmatrix} a_n \\ b_n \end{bmatrix} := \begin{bmatrix} 7 & 5 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix} ^{n-1} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$
then $x_n = \frac{a_n}{b_n}$.  Now, to find the powers of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 7 & 5 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$ all you need to do is to diagonalize it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method that I read from a book. Yet I did not think deeply why it works in general.

---

If there exists real numbers $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $r$ such that

$$\frac{a_{n+1}-\beta}{a_{n+1}-\alpha}=r\cdot\frac{a_n-\beta}{a_n-\alpha}$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then the sequence $\{b_n\}$, where $b_n=\frac{a_n-\beta}{a_n-\alpha}$, would be geometric and can be solved easily.

So our job is to find such $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $r$.

Substituting the recurring equation,

\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}-\beta}{a_{n+1}-\alpha}&=\frac{\frac{7a_n+5}{a_n+3}-\beta}{\frac{7a_n+5}{a_n+3}-\alpha} \\
&=\frac{7a_n+5-\beta(a_n+3)}{7a_n+5-\alpha(a_n+3)} \\
&=\frac{(7-\beta)a_n+(5-3\beta)}{(7-\alpha)a_n+(5-3\alpha)} \\
&=\frac{7-\beta}{7-\alpha}\cdot\frac{a_n-\left(-\frac{5-3\beta}{7-\beta}\right)}{a_n-\left(-\frac{5-3\alpha}{7-\alpha}\right)}
\end{align}

Hence the trick should work if there is a solution for $\alpha=-\frac{5-3\alpha}{7-\alpha}$ and $\beta=-\frac{5-3\beta}{7-\beta}$ and $r=\frac{7-\beta}{7-\alpha}$.

Noting that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $u=-\frac{5-3u}{7-u}$.

\begin{align}
u&=-\frac{5-3u}{7-u} \\
u(7-u)&=-(5-3u) \\
u^2-4u-5&=0 \\
u&=-1\enspace\text{or}\enspace 5 \\
\end{align}

Take $(\alpha,\,\beta)=(-1,\,5)$. $r=\frac{7-5}{7-(-1)}=\frac{1}{4}$ follows.

$$b_1=\frac{a_1-\beta}{a_1-\alpha}=\frac{1-5}{1-(-1)}=-2$$

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

$$b_n=r^{n-1}\cdot b_1=\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1}(-2)=\frac{-8}{4^n}$$

Back substitute into $b_n=\frac{a_n-\beta}{a_n-\alpha}$.

\begin{align}
\frac{-8}{4^n}&=\frac{a_n-5}{a_n-(-1)} \\
-8(a_n+1)&=4^n(a_n-5) \\
a_n&=\frac{5\cdot 4^n-8}{4^n+8}
\end{align}

The same result as given by *Mathematica*.

Comment: Can you show the book for me?

Answer (score 2):

The chracteristic equation of the given sequence is
$$y=\dfrac{7y+5}{y+3} \Leftrightarrow y_1 = 5 \lor y_2 = -1.$$
Let us consider the sequence
$$b_n = \dfrac{x_n-y_1}{x_n - y_2}=\dfrac{x_n-5}{x_n+1}.$$
We note that
$$b_{n+1}=\dfrac{x_{n+1}-5}{x_{n+1}+1}=\dfrac{\dfrac{7x_n+5}{x_n+3}-5}{\dfrac{7x_n+5}{x_n+3} + 1}=\dfrac{2x_n-10}{8x_n + 8} = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \dfrac{x_n-5}{x_n +1 }=\frac{1}{4} b_n.$$
Therefore $(b_n)$ is a geometric progression, with ratio $\dfrac{1}{4}$ and the first term
$$b_1 = \frac{x_1-5}{x_1+1}=\frac{1-5}{1+1}=\frac{-4}{2}=-2.$$
Therefore
$$b_{n+1}=b_1 \cdot \left (\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^n= - 2 \cdot \left (\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^n,$$
or equaivalently,
$$\dfrac{x_{n+1}-5}{x_{n+1}+1}=- 2 \cdot \left (\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^n \Leftrightarrow x_{n+1} = \frac{5\cdot 4^n - 2}{4^n +2}\Leftrightarrow x_n = \frac{5\cdot 4^n - 8}{4^n + 8}.$$